# Run "dotnet tool restore" to make the "dotnet-ef" command available

Tags: asp.net-core

[image]

I have try to find solution for this can some help please.

Comment: Did you run the "dotnet tool restore" command in a command window in your project folder? what happened? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-restore

Comment: @Rosco - i did it says 'Cannot find a manifest file.
For a list of locations searched, specify the "-d" option before the tool name.
No tools were restored.'

Answer (score 4):

This is most probably caused by a messed up tool cache ([see here in the source](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/4111d80adc284ff4419fba5539df9a92e32b3e49/src/Cli/dotnet/CommandFactory/CommandResolution/LocalToolsCommandResolver.cs#L92)), and it is a [known bug](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/11432) in .net sdk (fix added into the roadmap of .net 8, so let's see).

The workaround, as of today, is to clear the `toolResolverCache` folder and try to `dotnet tool restore` again.

- On mac, Linux: `rm -r $HOME/.dotnet/toolResolverCache`
- On Windows: `rmdir /s %USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\toolResolverCache`

Comment: I'd upvote this twice if I could. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This command will install latest version of dotnet-ef.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

If still not working, you could try install the right version like v3.1.1

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.1
```

You could try uninstall before install new one

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef
```

Add nuget package when finish install,

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

[After doing all the above, issue is still same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy8qA.png)

Comment: i did install. i can run dotnet-ef command in vs also in command prompt.

Comment: After doing all the above the issue is still the same. no change

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**
Go to the folder where your `.sln` file is.

**Step 2:**
Create a folder called `.config`. And create a file inside it named: `dotnet-tools.json`

Add the following content in it and save it:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "isRoot": true,
  "tools": {
    "dotnet-ef": {
      "version": "6.0.8",
      "commands": [
        "dotnet-ef"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 3:**
Go to your `.sln` folder, open `cmd` window and run:

`dotnet tool restore`

---

### Alternate Way:

**Step 1:**
Create manifest as outlined in this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/local-tools-how-to-use

**Step 2:**
Install ef as local tool:

`dotnet tool install dotnet-ef`

**Step 3:**
Restore your packages

`dotnet tool restore`